# How to AutoFixture.CreateAnonymous<>() on class with internal ctor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I have done something like the following

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    internal Bar(string id)
    {}
}

public static class Bars
{
     public static class TypeOne
     {
           public static readonly SimpleBar = new Bar("id-for-type1-simple-bar");
     }
}
```

now, I added an `InternalsVisibleTo` to my in my unit-test-assembly to be able to access the internal Bar ctor and then I did:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Register(() => new Bar(fixture.CreateAnonymous<string>()));
var foo = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Foo>();
```

Question:
Was that the "right" way to utilize AutoFixture or is there a better one?

Comment: The "right" way is to test only the public API of your System Under Test. Thus, InternalsVisibleTo is, at best, treatment of symptoms instead of the illness. Can't you make the constructor public?

Comment: @MarkSeemann: I could, but all possible values for instances of `Bar` are listed in the `static class Bars` - so there's no need to create other instances...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just do something like this instead?

```
fixture.Inject(Bars.TypeOne.SimpleBar);
```

This is all public. No need for InternalsVisibleTo, I think...

Comment: +1 this makes the most sense esp in light of your comment that the only permissible values are known by `Bars`

Answer (score 2):

This code works since you already have a public static class that references Bar, this works without setting the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute

```
        var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

        fixture.Inject(Bars.TypeOne.SimpleBar);

        var sut = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Foo>();

        sut.Should().NotBeNull();
        sut.Bar.Should().NotBeNull();
        sut.Bar.Should().Be(Bars.TypeOne.SimpleBar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Never ever go down the road of `InternalsVisibleTo` - Don't make me start the list, but it starts with every part of your system including all test helpers being strong named.

If you definitely can't (think long and hard about it - most of the time you're far better off putting internals you dont consider part of your public api into a namespace so they don't clutter anything - e.g. Xunit.Sdk and various `.Internal` sub-namespaces I've used for my employer), then the correct way to manage this exposing of stuff For Tests Only is the notion of [For Tests Only](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Logic%20in%20Production.html). NB the reason this has a name is that it is (correctly) called out as an antipattern in [the xUnit Test Patterns book](http://xunitpatterns.com/).

---

Now, to answer your question...

1. CONSIDER hiding stuff that users shouldnt generally require in a separate namespace
2. NEVER use `InternalsVisibleTo`
3. DONT use Test Only Code

Expose a factory which is only exposed in Internal (maybe `DEBUG`?) Builds of your software (but ideally you'd have it unconditional in another namespace):

```
#if INCLUDE_FOR_TEST_ONLY
public static class BarsForTestOnly
{
    public static Bar Create( string id )
    {
        return new Bar( id );
    }
}
#endif
```

And use it like this:

```
#if INCLUDE_FOR_TEST_ONLY
public class Facts
{

[Fact]
public void Fact()
{
    Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Register( ( string name ) => BarsForTestOnly.Create( name ) );
    var anonymousBar = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Bar>();
}

[Fact]
public void FactSyntax2() // Just a variant of Fact above
{
    Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Register<string, Bar>( BarsForTestOnly.Create );
    var anonymousBar = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Bar>();
}

[Fact]
public void UsingFromFactory()
{
    Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customize<Bar>(  x=> x.FromFactory<string>( BarsForTestOnly.Create ) );
    var anonymousBar = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Bar>();
}
#endif
```

---

Alternately, to make what you have Just Work, you can do:

```
[Fact]
public void UsingCtor()
{
    Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Register( ( string name )=> new Bar( name ) );
    var anonymousBar = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Bar>();
}
```

Comment: +1 Another alternative to 'hiding' things in namespaces is to consider the use of interfaces as a sort of access modifier in itself: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/02/28/InterfacesAreAccessModifiers.aspx

Comment: @Mark Seemann: Have read and valued the insights in that article but it didnt come to mind here. Def a technique to consider in this space. (Though obviously in this specific case case, it (methods on an explicitly implemented interface [only]) only becomes valuable after you've got yourself an instance of an object, which is the chicken the OP was after).